# Receiving a xmlstring with asmack with a corrupted string

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I built a XMPP Server with a Java Client as Subscriber and Publisher this thing uses the original Smacklib.
The other Part is a Android Client with a lib called asmack7 and asmack-beem(testet both). The Androidlibs seems to work but not fully.

What i do is to create a Node with the Payload like "testname".
If the Computer or the Mobilephone sends this and the PC receives the node everything is ok. 
If the Androidphone receives the node, it looks like this "nulltestnamenull" so it looks like the nodeget is having a problem with the elements in the xml file.

My code seems right and i dont get any errors.

Does anyone here had the same issue and found a work arround or solution of this?

Comment: "_My code seems right_" how should we know without seeing it. I think your code is the cause for the null pre- and suffix.

Comment: Why should it be wrong? i get and read the node/item the same way on both systems. The Client on PC doesnt have the nulls the Android client does. Only thing is different is the lib